# What is the difference between Twilio Sip and Twilio Client?

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

I noticed that there is a Client noun in the Twilio documentation. Is Client a Sip product? Would I use Client to connect to a Sip phone?

Answer (score 1):

The [`<Dial><Client>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/client) verb is for dialing from the Twilio Computer Telephony Integrated (CTI) VoIP solution, or what is called Twilio Client. Twilio Client can be integrated into a browser, an iOS application and/or an Android application. Twilio Client is different from Twilio Sip. Twilio Client is used for calling to or from in-app soft phones whereas Twilio Sip is for calling to or from a PBX (physical or hosted) and/or a Sip enabled device. In Twilio, calling Sip endpoints is accomplished by using the [`<Dial><Sip>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sip) verb.

Sip and Client usage in Twilio is a little different. For example, to call a Twilio Client soft phone, you could write:

```
<Dial>
    <Client>Agent1</Client>
</Dial>
```

On the other hand, to call a Twilio Sip endpoint, you could write:

```
<Dial>
    <Sip>sip:agent1@example.com</Sip>
</Dial>
```

Twilio Client is useful for building solutions where you don't have a PBX or SIP hardware already in place. Twilio SIP can be used to add new functionality or extend an existing SIP setup.